# Getting All Users Uid from Firebase / Flutter/Dart

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My application is kind of a poll application. So the admin asks a question, and users respond to that question, and every data is stored in Firestore. In the admin page, the admin can see the question that he/she created, and when the admin clicks the question, he/she can see the answers of users to this question.

On the answers page, I am trying to reach every user's uid but I couldn't achieve this. I can print them but I can't use them in a way. I think I make some mistakes with Firebase functions.

This is an example of a method that I am trying to return the list includes of the specific question. But this function doesn't return anything.

```
List getUserIDData() {
    List<String> growableList = [];
    List<String> userAnswerList = [];
    String adminQuestion = "What is the reason of life?";
    Firestore.instance.collection("user").getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((element) {
        growableList.add(element.documentID);
      });
      for (int i = 0; i < growableList.length; i++) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("user")
            .document(growableList[i])
            .collection("answers")
            .where("adminQuestion", isEqualTo: adminQuestion)
            .getDocuments()
            .then((snapshot) {
          snapshot.documents.forEach((element) {
            userAnswerList.add(element["userAnswer"]);
          });
        });
        print(i);
      }
    });
    return growableList;
  }
```

I also tried something with StreamBuilder, but still, after Firestore.instance, everything is deleted automatically. In Firestore, everything looks good, but after it finished growableList doesn't stay the same and this function returns null.

Do you have any suggestions to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are using a very old version of FlutterFire, for example the following has been changed:

- BREAKING: getDocuments/get has been updated to accept an instance of GetOptions (see below).
- DEPRECATED: documents has been deprecated in favor of docs.
- DEPRECATED: documentID has been deprecated in favor of id.

You might want to [migrate to a newer version](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#firestore).

With `snapshot.documents` you get a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>` [according to the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html). So I looked at the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and was surprised that you apply `element["userAnswer"]` directly to it. [According to the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) you have to use `element.data()` to get the data.

If that doesn't help I would need more information in the form of output what's behind the `element` variables.

Comment: This is my last work to do to finish my project, so that I can't migrate to a newer version at all right now. Actually, if I print element["userAnswer"], it gives me the right data. But I don't want to print, I want to use it in a ListTile. So, how can I take that value as a variable and use it in another part. By the way, element has two type of variable, one is "userAnswer", another is "adminQuestion"

Comment: Okay, whether you migrate or not is up to you. Of course, it's not easy to help you because the documentation is no longer correct. The function as it is should return a list of document ids of all users (growableList). Is that the case? Is that what you want to return or do you expect userAnswerList?

Comment: growableList should return a list of user ids and userAnswerList should return a list that includes answers of users. I solved the problem with streambuilder by the way, but still I am curious about why this method does not return list, it returns null both growableList and userAnswerList

Comment: I wonder what the lists look like after each .add. Does the addition work properly?

Comment: Yes, after each .add method, it adds because when I print growableList everytime, it gives me the right data in the console. But when you go out from Firestore.instance, growableList includes nothing.

Comment: I just saw that the function is not `async`. The query is asynchronous, so the query and adding the data to the lists is not yet finished when the list is returned with `return`. Therefore, I recommend marking the function as `async` and using `await` when querying the data. I hope that this is the solution.